# Including API routes in Express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm learning MEAN stack with 'Getting MEAN with...' book, and problem is older Express version in books than i use.

> The first step is to tell our application that we’re adding more routes to look out for,
>   and when it should use them. We already have a line in app.js to require the server
>   application routes, which we can simply duplicate and set the path to the API routes
>   as follows:

```
var routes = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var routesApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');
```

> Next we need to tell the application when to use the routes. We currently have the following line in app.js telling the application to check the server application routes for
>   all incoming requests:

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

Notice the '/' as the first parameter. This enables us to specify a subset of URL s for
which the routes will apply. For example, we’ll define all of our API routes starting
with /api/ . By adding the line shown in the following code snippet we can tell the application to use the API routes only when the route starts with /api :

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', routesApi);
```

And there's listing of my app.js file:

```
    var express = require('express')
  , others = require('./app_server/routes/others')
  , locations = require('./app_server/routes/locations')
  , routesApi = require('/app_api/routes/index')
  , ;

require('./app_server/models/db')

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/app_server/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes
// LOCATION PAGES
app.get('/', locations.homeList);
app.get('/location', locations.locInfo);
app.get('/location/review/new', locations.addReview);
// OTHER PAGES
app.get('/about', others.about);

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Can someone explain me how to do the same in my Express version ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Express 4, this is done using [`Router Middleware`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router). More info is available on [Express Routing here.](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

A `Router` is simply a mini express app that you can define [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) and routes on that should all be packaged together, ie `/api` should all use `apiRouter`. Here is what `apiRouter` could look like

#### apiRouter.js

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router(); // Create our Router Middleware

// GET / route
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return res.status(200).send('GET /api received!');
});


// export our router middleware
module.exports = router;
```

Your main Express app would stay the same, so you would add your router using a `require()` to import the actual file, and then inject the router with `use()`

#### Express Server File

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var apiRouter = require('../apiRouter');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/', apiRouter);

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('listening on ' + port);
});
```